# Sails.js CORS for post method

Tags: sails.js

I was able to use CORS for a specific controller using a GET request like the following:

```
'get /url': {
        controller: 'somecontroller',
        action: 'someaction',
        cors: true
    },
```

However if I try using POST like the following, I get "Access Denied" error:

```
'post /url': {
            controller: 'somecontroller',
            action: 'someaction',
            cors: true
        },
```

How do I setup cors for a post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my limited research I found out that simply adding "cors: true" to the controller doesn't solve the problem. Sails is still expecting a `csrf` token for the post method. In the `bootstrap.js` file under `config` folder, I added the following code at the bottom to disable `csrf` token on the route by using the following:

```
sails.config.csrf.routesDisabled = '/url';
```

If you have better solutions, please post them here. Thanks!

Edit: You can also change this in the `config/csrf.js` file. Change `module.exports.csrf = true;` to:

```
module.exports.csrf = {
    routesDisabled: '/url',
};
```

You might have to use it for your apis

```
module.exports.csrf = {
    routesDisabled: '/api/*',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in config/routes.js before declaring routes put :

`'OPTIONS /*': function(req, res) {
        res.send(200);
    },`

and in config/cors.js try to put :

```
module.exports.cors = {

allRoutes: true,

origin: '*',

credentials: true,

methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',

headers: 'content-type, access-control-allow-origin, authorization'
```

};